# The test returns true, while it should return false and vice versa

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, mockito

Continuation of my thread [How to properly test a Spring Boot using Mockito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45760467/how-to-properly-test-a-spring-boot-using-mockito/45761352#45761352). There was another problem.

Well, this method

```
@GetMapping("/checkUsernameAtRegistering")
public HttpEntity<Boolean> checkUsernameAtRegistering(@RequestParam String username) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(!userService.existsByUsername(username));
}
```

After receiving the username and checking in the database should return false if the username exists.
However, the test

```
@Test
public void textExistsUsername() throws Exception {
    mockMvc
            .perform(get("/checkUserData/checkUsername")
            .param("username", "jonki97"))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(content().string("false"));
}
```

Returns true. I have a user with that username, and the method should return false. However, it is not.

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Response content 
Expected :false
Actual   :true
```

I think I understand syntax well

```
.andExpect(content().string("false"));
```

I'm expecting a string of false value. How to tell the service what to return?

Comment: Your sample "works" for me. Assuming your paths are actually correct (`/checkUserData/checkUsername` vs `/checkUsernameAtRegistering`). Please post a [mcve].

Comment: In another forum I got the answer: 'And where do you have the setup of this site mocked to return true? O_O Because you locked him up but nowhere is there any expectation. The miracle that does not work at all, probably mockito defaults gives there a nice moc which on all unexpected calls returns null / 0 / false.' 
But I do not know what it is.

Comment: I guess your code splitter do not fit together. You explicitely declare the expect to be false, but the shown AssertionError says "Expected: true".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can mock service's return with Mockito's [`when`](http://www.baeldung.com/mockito-behavior).

```
@Test
public void textExistsUsername() throws Exception {
    when(userService.existsByUsername("jonki97")).thenReturn(true);
    mockMvc
            .perform(get("/checkUserData/checkUsername")
            .param("username", "jonki97"))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(content().string("false"));
}
```

Comment: Sorry but that does not work. Continue the same error. https://zapodaj.net/1db46416c9669.png.html

Comment: I made a mistake, it should be `when(userService.existsByUsername("jonki97")).thenReturn(true)`